# detecting email account from within an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email

Is there a way to know the email addresses to which the user has linked his iPhone to from within an iPhone application?

Comment: it is not possible to get it via sdk, the user would have to select it from their list of contacts.

Comment: But your email account is not displayed in the Address Book. Isn't there an alternative?

Comment: Maybe you could do it the (sort of) old fashion way by prompting the user for it? And store the information in a NSString using a NSTextField.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `AccountEmailAddresses` function of [ABGetMe](https://github.com/0xced/ABGetMe) for iOS. Make sure to read and understand the *Limitations* section of the README.